# CoC boosts to NG+ or just difficulty?

Tags: dark-souls-2

OK so to explain what I mean. When you join Covenant of Champions, it will boost the difficulty of the game to NG+ difficulty, cut off co-op summoning, and (I think) increases the chance to be invaded. But I want to know if it also adds items that you would find in NG+ as well? Like the extra boss souls (Old Witch's Soul, Old King's Soul) or other items (Southern Ritual Band +2 from Scorpioness Najka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Company of Champions does not boost the difficulty to NG+. It increases the difficulty by both decreasing the damage you do and increasing the damage of enemies, but unlike new game +, the enemies' health and the amount of souls they drop remain the same.

According to the [Dark Souls II wikidot](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/company-of-champions) the Company of Champions decreases your damage by 20% and increases enemy damage by ~33%.

Thus you also won't encounter the changes of NG+, like extra enemies or new item drops. The only way to get the additional boss items and souls without advancing to NG+ is to use bonfire ascetics.