# Great Chaos Fireball from Chancellor Wellager

Tags: achievements, ps4, dark-souls-2

I'm going for the platinum trohpy hopefully prior to DS3 hitting the US next week and I think I'm down to just a handful of spells/hexes/miracles.

One of the NPCs sells a spell or two that you would otherwise get from covenant ranking.  Info on [Chancellor Wellager](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Chancellor+Wellager).  According to this, bonfire ascetics do not change his inventory, but does anyone know if joining the [covenant of champions](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Company+of+Champions) would in effect make your game a ng++ (if you're currently in ng+ that is)

Comment: I've never tried this, but I think it's unlikely. That article seems to say that the covenant of champions makes the game *as hard as* NG+, but not that it actually *counts as* NG+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, joining the CoC [does not increase the playthrough](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174997/coc-boosts-to-ng-or-just-difficulty), it only simulates the difficulty. Wellager will still only sell his extra wares once you have defeated the game at least twice, regardless of Bonfire Ascetics, or Covenants.

To be specific - joining the Company of Champions will only change the game by:

- Reducing damage dealt by 50%
- Increasing damage taken by 50%
- Cut off summoning (including NPC summons)